# why composition of two relations is defined in this way?

Tags: logic

the idea of "composition" as I understand is that
given (a,b) which belongs to R and (b,k) belonging to S the composition of R and S is the relation W such that (a,k) is an element of W

now my question is this:
why such a situation where (a,b) belongs to R and (b,k) belongs to S is interesting?

my thought is that it is interesting because of this result

let p(a,b) be an open statement

if p(a,b) and p(b,k) are true then p(a,k) is also true

however, I don't know how to prove the above implication so I need help

Answer (score 2):

The general reason why it is interesting to study the composition of maps (which is a special type of composition of relations) is that it very frequently occurring problem. If $A,B,C$ are some sets and you have characteristics of a map $A \to B$ and another one $B \to C$, and you would like to study a direct relationship, which may borrow nice properties from both maps. This is especially frequent when $A,B,C$ are really the same set, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$.

For example, $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ can be considered as a composition of $g(x) = \sin x$ with $h(x) = x^2$, and knowing properties of any two of $f,g,h$ will tell you a lot about the properties of the third one, since you have $f = g \circ h$...

**UPDATE**

Specifically transitivity is very useful in many places, like sorting or root-finding algorithms, since it is at the heart of comparing numbers...

Comment: thanks, but can you provide me with a proof for the implication above or recommend something to read from

Comment: One application of transitivity is comparison, i.e. if $a>b$ and $b>c$ then $a>c$. This lies at the heart of the [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) for root finding and the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

A relation $W$ satisfying the properties you mention is the transitive closure of $R$.  Transitivity is interesting because it shows up in many situations in real life.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation

The simplest relation with transitive properties is ordering: if $a > b$ and $b > k$ then $a > k$